# RXJS Behaviour Subject outputting Duplicates on First load

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, rxjs

Im building an Ionic 2 app and when the app loads up it should show the users near you, Which works but it shows duplicate values, I understand that this may be part of the behaviour of behaviour subject as it shows the initial values and then whatever comes next ? Is there a way to just show the values after there are all loaded up.. in my head it should work like an array that fills up then and only then does it display either that or it should pop entries off as it fills up

Here is my Service.ts which pushes the users to the component using next

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation, Geoposition, BackgroundGeolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import { Fb } from './firebase';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { User } from './user';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

declare var GeoFire: any


@Injectable()
export class LocationTracker {

public firebaseRef: any;
public geoFire: any;
public subject: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(0);

constructor( public zone: NgZone, public fire:Fb, public user:User) {
    this.firebaseRef = this.fb.ref('geofire');
    this.geoFire     = new GeoFire(this.firebaseRef);
}

UsersNearME() : Observable<any> {
    this.nearme.length = 0;
    let geoQuery = this.geoFire.query({
    center: [this.lat, this.lng],
    radius: 4.609 //kilometers
    });
    geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key, location, distance) => {

const sender = this.fb.ref('/users/'+ key  );
    sender.on('value',  (snapshot) => {
        const profile = snapshot.val().profile;
        this.nearme.push({ 
            userid: key,
            userloc: location,
        });
        this.subject.next(this.nearme);
        // 
    }); 
    });
return this.subject.asObservable();
}
}
```

My Component.ts is as follows and basically subscribes to the users service

```
    import { Component, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';

    @Component({
    selector: 'members',
    templateUrl: 'members.html'
    })
    export class MembersOverviewPage  implements OnInit {

    public usersNearMe;

    constructor(locationTracker: LocationTracker,
                zone: NgZone,) {
    }

        ngOnInit() {
                this.zone.run(() => {
                    setTimeout(() => {  
                        try {
                            this.locationTracker.UsersNearME().filter(data => data != null).subscribe( data => {
                            if( data ) {
                                    this.usersNearMe = data;
                                    this.loader.dismiss();
                                }
                            }, (error) => {
                                alert("are you online ? ");
                            }, () => {
                            // this.loader.dismiss();
                            });

                        } catch (e) { 
                            console.log( " error "+ JSON.stringify(e));
                        }                           
                    }, 1000);
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is how you create the `this.nearme` array. You push a user to it, then you emit. You push another value, then you emit. Wouldn't it be better to retrieve all nearby users **and then** emit the array ONCE?

Answer (score 3):

That is what `BehaviorSubject` is for, it first gives value that is there, and after that all next values. If you do not want first value, then change it to simply `Subject`.

```
public subject: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

Maybe `ReplaySubject` could also work for you:

http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/subjects/replay_subject/index.html

**UPDATE:**

```
    this.nearme.push({ 
        userid: key,
        userloc: location,
    });
    this.subject.next(this.nearme);
```

As I understand this code, you increment array with new values and want the whole array to be shown to subscribers again? If not,

```
    this.subject.next({ 
        userid: key,
        userloc: location,
    });
```

Comment: Then I cant get the last value

Comment: @REPTILE Have you taken a look at replaysubject with buffer length 1?

Comment: No but I will now

Comment: Tried it out there and Im still getting dupes

Comment: Thanks for the assistance but unfortunately this multiplies the results x4

Comment: @REPTILE it seems your problem is not because of Subjects at all, you have two nested callbacks with array push. Probably the array push and next should be in first callback (geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key, location, distance) => ) as the second, nested callback snapshot is not used at all. You can simply console.log content of the array and see if it actually dublicated there.

Comment: The second snapshot is used, its assigned to the variable profile

Comment: @REPTILE it is assigned to some local scope variable which is never used. Nevertheless, snapshot is never used in subject next parameters. 
 this.nearme.push({ 
            userid: key,
            userloc: location,
        });
        this.subject.next(this.nearme);

Comment: Ah sorry, man I just realised I have trimmed the code you are seeing.. basically in the code there is more parameters from that inner snapshot which are getting pushed into the array.. sorry again for the confusion, basically the first snapshot gets the locations and the second one gets that users details and adds them to the array push